# how to select rows from table A that do not exist in the table B?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in which about 80% of primary keys is the same. How can I SELECT:

- all rows from table A where there is no primary key in other table (e.g. row have the primary as 432, but there is no 432 in table B - so we want to select it)
- all rows from either table when there is primary key of e.g. 784 in both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select common records:

```
Select * from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.id = b.id
```

select unique tableA records:

```
Select * from tableA
where id not in (select id from TableB)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

Try Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM
table_A a LEFT JOIN table_b b on b.id=a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have the same schema you can use
MINUS for the first
INTERSECT for the second

Answer (score 0):

For the case of finding rows in tableA which do not have rows in tableB, you can specify WHERE tableB.id IS NOT NULL after joining:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE tableB.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from yourTable a
left join yourNextTable b 
on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID is null
```